# Ethernet camera is not reachable

Tags: raspbian, networking, camera

I'm working with one Raspberry Pi2 connected to the wifi net (dongle) and one AXIS camera connected via ethernet.

The raspberry has a Static IP and also the camera.

Raspberry: 10.76.80.30
Camera: 192.168.2.110

On the camera there is a software developed by Axis useful to count the people, I can retrive the counter from the internal camera counter with a http request.

I've recently upgraded the operative system on the raspberry (Raspbian) and now the camera is not working, I can't ping it and I can't reach it, but the configuration file are the same as before because I've modified all of them.

Can someone helps me? please.

/etc/network/interfaces --> file configuration

```
auto lo
iface lo net loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.10
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.76.80.30
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 10.76.83.254
   wpa-ssid Test
   wpa-psk testpassword
   epa-scan-ssid 1
```

Comment: "The raspberry has a Static IP" - NO it doesn't.
See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have upgraded the RPi, camera configuration most probably didn't change (though I would still check if I can ping it from another computer). I suggest you check that the configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` is effective by running

```
ip addr show dev eth0
```

It should say along the lines

```
inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
```

If you don't get this line, the issue in the RPi. You might want to check the driver used with the Ethernet chip, any network managers or custom scripts that could interfere, and so on.

If you get this line, the issue is likely elsewhere. Check your cables, your router configuration (if any) and the camera.

Comment: I've tried the command and the output is: 2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 disc fifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000  link/ether b8:27:eb:02:06:fb bed ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet6 fe80::e5d0:9520:f112:5f52/64 scope link tentative valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                 what it means?

Comment: It looks like `eth0` is not configured and down. Maybe you should try `ip link set eth0 up`? BTW, don't you miss `auto eth0` line in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: I've added "auto eth0" and then I've rebooted the system but nothing changed, I've also tried the command "ip link set eth0 up" and I've tried to ping the camera but It isn't working, I've got destination host Unreachable

Comment: does `eth0` get an IP address when you run `ip link set eth0 up`? Is it the one you expect (192.168.2.10)? Feel free to update your question with these details, it will be more readable that way and it will aslo bump the question up, so more people will get to see it and help.

Comment: No, when I'm running the command "ip link set eth0 up" nothing happens, is it possible that the ethernet port is not working? is there a way to test it?